JS- In words ending by (an , replace the ending (an
In words ending by (an , I want to replace the ending (an by an when the word is preceded by le or du . Like removing the opening parenthesis. I tried many variants without success. Last one is:
result = result.replace(/(?<=\b(le|du)\s)\(an\b/g, 'an');

i also tried amongst others
(/(?<=\b(?:le|du)\s)\b(\w+)\(an\b/g, '$1an')

Example string: le prézid(an , should return le prézidan
OK: this works, with accents;
result.replace(/(\b(?:le|du)\s\p{L}*)(\(an\b)/gmu, '$1'+'an');

thanks guys

what goes wrong? do you have some examples of in- and output?

example added. maybe the accentuated char is problem.

Yes, the accentuated I guess too! With newer JS (ES9?) you can use the u flag. Even if it does not make \b word boundaries unicode aware you could still use such as \p{L} for unicode letter. Try to replace \b((?:le|du)\s\p{L}+)\(an\b with $1an.

Since \b is not made Unicode aware with all these flags, .replace(/\b(?:le|du)\s+(\p{Alphabetic}+)\((an)(?![^\W\d_])/ivg, '$1$2') might be a bit more precise.

Strange it shoud work, but no.  Tested with  non-accentuated words. still not working. I need a rest. Maybe the lookbehind should look at the second word preceding.

Ah, I did not capture all the article/preposition before the word. .replace(/\b((?:le|du)\s+\p{Alphabetic}+)\((an)(?![^\W\d_])/ivg, '$1$2') should be the right code.

Mind that \b is not working for accented characters anyway.
